# rsync file between two android device using rsync

Tags: android, rsync

```
  try {
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/xbin/su -c sh");
        DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());


        os.writeBytes("/system/xbin/rsync -avzru  /data/shareData/ 192.168.84.111:/data/shareData/");
        String output=new String();



        os.flush();
 } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.i("rsync",""+e.getMessage());
 }
```

but not give any log output,and also not rsync sucess. can you give me some advice.

Answer (score 0):

i have solve

```
public static void startRsync() {


    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {

                    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c sh");
                    OutputStream os = process.getOutputStream();

                    writeLine( os, "/system/xbin/rsync --daemon --config=/etc/rsyncd/rsyncd.conf");
                    os.flush();
                    //process.waitFor();


            }
            catch ( IOException e ) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

//              catch (InterruptedException e) {
//                  e.printStackTrace();
//              }
            }
        };
        thread.start();

```
    // sleep to give some time to statusRsync to detect process
            try{
              Thread.currentThread().sleep(2000);//sleep for 2000 ms
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

}
```